# OSGi Code Coverage during Integration Testing

Tags: maven, osgi, integration-testing, code-coverage, soapui

I am running integration tests on `OSGi` bundles using `SOAPUI`. So far I have integrated SOAPUI with Maven which runs integration tests on OSGi bundles*(running in `Apache Karaf`)*. I am trying to find out how can I further enhance my `pom.xml` to calculate *`code coverage`* during runtime for the bundles?

Can anyone plz suggest some points?

I have the following pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.m2m.aricent.parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>CustRestExampleOsgi</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>CustRestExampleOsgii</name>


  <modules>
      <module>M2mCustImplProvider</module>
      <module>M2mCustInterface</module>
      <module>M2mRestCustConsumer</module>
  </modules>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <karaf.deploy.build.folder>
        G:\apache-karaf-3.0.0.RC1\deploy
    </karaf.deploy.build.folder>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- needed to execute Integration tests instrumented with Cobertura -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
      <id>eviwarePluginRepository</id>
      <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
   </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
     <id>cobertura-it-maven-plugin-maven2-release</id>
     <url>http://cobertura-it-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/releases</url>
     <snapshots>
         <enabled>false</enabled>
     </snapshots>
     <releases>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
     </releases>
 </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

  <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>eviware</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                <projectFile>C:\Documents and Settings\gur31659.AD\workspace\CustomerRestfulExampleOSGi\test-classes\cust.xml</projectFile>
                <outputFolder>C:\Documents and Settings\gur31659.AD\workspace\CustomerRestfulExampleOSGi\test_output</outputFolder>
                <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>wsn-server-test</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
             <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-it-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>xml</format>
                    <format>html</format>
                </formats>
                <check>
                    <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
                </check>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cobertura-clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>cobertura-instrument</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>cobertura-report</id>
                    <phase>pre-site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.5.201403032054</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                    <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                   </execution>
                    <!--
                        Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                        is passed as VM argument when Maven the Failsafe plugin is executed.
                    -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <destFile>${jacoco.it.execution.data.file}</destFile>
                            <!--
                                Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                                for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                            -->
                            <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>


                    <!--
                        Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after
                        integration tests have been run.
                    -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <dataFile>${jacoco.it.execution.data.file}</dataFile>
                            <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>                   
            </executions>
        </plugin>
                <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.2.v20120308</version>
            <configuration>
                <stopPort>18043</stopPort>
                <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>18042</port>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Needed in order to to code coverage on SoapUI tests -->
                        <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-classes/cobertura</classesDirectory>
                        <useTestScope>true</useTestScope>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                        <contextPath>/myIntegrationTestsContext</contextPath>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <minimumTokens>20</minimumTokens>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-it-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>report-only</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

I suggest that you should try [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/). Jacoco can be configured as a [java agent](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html), so it can work with any Java application. In this case, you should configure Jacoco on the Karaf server where you deploy the bundles.

You can configure it as a TCP server so you can check the coverage reports live from Eclipse (it has an Eclipse plugin as well to connect).

**Extra:**

We use Jacoco with our [maven plugin](https://github.com/everit-org/eosgi-maven-plugin) that starts an OSGi container and runs tests on them within the integration-test phase of the build. In case felix or equinox is enough, you can use it as well.

It supports creating custom dist packages so if you bundle your Karaf server as a dist package, it could also be used. Sadly, there still not much documentation about creating custom server types.